# Problem in creating dynamic form in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a form which can take students exam number. These exam number fields come dynamically according to the exam type. Currently, I am getting the values of the last student as shown in the image. I need to create the form dynamically on both sides, according to the student and according to the exam type.
[image: 1]

```js
    marksForm: FormGroup;
    
    constructor(
        private academicProgramAndSemesterWiseOfferedCourseService: AcademicProgramAndSemesterWiseOfferedCourseService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) {
        this.createMarksForm();
    }
    
    createMarksForm(): void {
        this.marksForm = this.formBuilder.group({
           numberFields: this.formBuilder.array([
               this.formBuilder.control('')
           ])
        });
    }

    get numberFields() {
        return this.marksForm.get('numberFields') as FormArray;
    }

/*
    addNumberFields() {
        this.numberFields.push(this.formBuilder.control(''));
    }
*/

    findOfferedSection(academicProgramId: string, semesterNumber: any, courseId: string, sectionNumber: any): void {
        this.academicProgramAndSemesterWiseOfferedCourseService
            .findOfferedSection(academicProgramId, semesterNumber, courseId, sectionNumber)
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data.body);
                this.offeredSection = data.body;

                for (let i = 0; i < this.offeredSection.exam.examTypeList.length - 1; i++) {
                    this.numberFields.push(this.formBuilder.control(''));
                }
            }, error => {
                console.log('GOT AN ERROR => ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            })
    }

    saveData() {
        console.log(this.marksForm.get('numberFields').value);
    }
```

```html
<div class="section pb-48">
                                <form id="gradeUploadForm" fxLayout="column" fxFlex [formGroup]="marksForm" (ngSubmit)="saveData()">
                                    <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="100" fxLayoutGap="0.7%">
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>SI</th>
                                                <th>ID</th>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <th>Batch</th>
                                                <th>CGPA</th>
                                                <th>Registration Type</th>
                                                <th *ngFor="let examType of offeredSection.exam?.examTypeList">{{examType.name}}</th>
                                                <th>Total</th>
                                                <th>GP</th>
                                                <th>Grade</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr *ngFor="let student of offeredSection.registeredStudentList; let i = index">
                                                <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
                                                <td>{{student.student.id}}</td>
                                                <td>{{getFullNameFromName(student.student.name)}}</td>
                                                <td>{{student.student.batchId}}</td>
                                                <td>3.5</td>
                                                <td>{{student.registrationType}}</td>

                                                <td *ngFor="let alias of numberFields.controls; let j = index" formArrayName="numberFields">
                                                    <mat-form-field class="w-100-p" appearance="outline">
                                                        <mat-label></mat-label>
                                                        <label>
                                                            <input matInput type="number" [formControlName]="j">
                                                        </label>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    --
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    3.54
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    A+
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>

                                    </div>
                                    <button mat-raised-button>Save</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
```

What can I do now?

Comment: It's quite unclear what the issue is

Comment: Would you please see the image description?